# How to concatenate tables in a for loop R

Tags: r

I'm processing tot of tables (txt format) for different cases (sample) , all the tables looks like this:

```
Sample  Chromosome  Start     End   Num_probes  Segment_Mean
1             1     3301765 8024757 3057         0.3208
1             1     8029121 8164570 66           0.8332
1             1     8164896 8630844 220          0.3059
1             1     8658852 8890987 157          0.5415
```

I want to process all together, and for doing that I'm using the following code

```
fileList <- list.files( ,pattern=".txt")
for (i in fileList){
  #print(i)
  tbl <- read.table(i, sep="\t", as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE)
  tbl$Sample <- i
  tbl1 <-tbl[tbl$Chromosome == 1, ]
  #print(tbl1)
  write.table(tbl1, paste("chr1_", i, sep="") , sep="\t", col.names=T, row.names = F, quote=F)

}
```

I would like concatenate all the tables in only one as follow:

```
Sample  Chromosome  Start     End   Num_probes  Segment_Mean
    1             1     3301765 8024757 3057         0.3208
    1             1     8029121 8164570 66           0.8332
    1             1     8164896 8630844 220          0.3059
    1             1     8658852 8890987 157          0.5415
    2             1    .....
    2             1    ..... 
    3             1    ....
```

I've try to use `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE),list(tbl1))`inside the loop but it doesn't woork, and I've also try `new_tbl = do.call(cbind, tbl1)` but it takes the last df only... any ideas pleas?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the chain merge when you intend to append (i.e., concatenate). Use `rbind` and not `cbind`.

Comment: From your expected output it looks like you want `rbind` as in appending rows, rather than `cbind` which is for adding columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `do.call`, when you save your tables in a list:

```
filenames <- list.files(your_location, pattern = "*.txt")
tbl <- lapply(filenames, function(x){
                            read.table(x, sep="\t", as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE)}
new_tbl <- do.call(rbind, tbl)
new_tbl <- new_tbl[new_tbl$Chromosome == 1, ]
```